# Plot route on map in Python (Windows)

Tags: python

I have longitude and latitude information of a route and I want to plot this route (as line) on a map. I'm very familiar with MATLAB where I only need the following two lines

```
geoplot(latdeg, londeg, 'LineWidth', 2);
geobasemap topographic
```

During some research I found the `geoplot` library but I cannot install this library to work properly on Windows (I'm using Visual Studio Code). When I execute `py -m pip install geoplot` I get the following error

`UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.7.2 or later installed, or installation may fail.`

When I install GEOS, only version 0.2.3 and as far as I saw at their website, this is the current version. My current Python version is 3.9.7.

Is there any simpler way to draw a line on a map?

PS: Till now I really like python but I always run into various conflicts with different versions not supporting another version of a library and so on. This is very annoying....

Comment: Not solely. I'd also be happy if someone could give me a lead towards another way to plot a route on a map (preferably without running into loads of issues with dependencies). Edit: There was a comment to rephrase the topic of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Some [documentation](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/installation.html) says:

> Installation geoplot is Python 3.6+ only.
>
> **With Conda (Recommended)**
>
> If you haven’t already, install conda.
> Then run `conda install geoplot -c conda-forge` and you’re done.
> This works on all platforms (Linux, macOS, and Windows).
>
> **Without Conda**
>
> You can install geoplot using `pip install geoplot`.
> Use caution however, as this probably will not work on
> Windows, and possibly will not work on macOS and Linux.

Comment: I read this already but pip didn't work (as described above) and I also still have troubles with conda install (I guess this is due to an installation or configuration issue with anaconda). Furthermore, it be nice that my code also runs on mobile devices. I doubt that this will work if I already have such massive troubles on my PC.